# Scala: toArray method and map method

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary

I am trying to do something in scala.

```
scala> val x = Array(Array(8.524, 6.375, 17.043), Array(1.754, 3.509, -1.754), Array(12.69, -12.69, 25.38),Array(4.355, 3.687, 2.876))
x: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(8.524, 6.375, 17.043), Array(1.754, 3.509, -1.754), Array(12.69, -12.69, 25.38), Array(4.355, 3.687, 2.876))

scala> val y = Array(1.0, -1.0, 2.0)
y: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, -1.0, 2.0)
```

I tried to add them like:

```
Array(Array(8.524 + 1.0, 6.375 + (-1.0), 17.043 + 2),Array(1.754 + 1.0, 3.509 + (-1.0), -1.754 + 2), Array(....)......)
```

To do above thing, my code is

```
val result = for(i <- 0 until x.length) yield {
  for(j <- 0 until y.length) yield x(i)(j) + y(j)
}
```

the result is

```
result: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double]] = Vector(Vector(9.524, 5.375, 19.043), Vector(2.754, 2.509, 0.246), Vector(13.69, -13.69, 27.38), Vector(5.355, 2.687, 4.8759999999999994))
```

I used `toArray` method on `result`, but get `Array[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double]] = Array(Vector(9.524, 5.375, 19.043), Vector(2.754, 2.509, 0.246), Vector(13.69, -13.69, 27.38), Vector(5.355, 2.687, 4.8759999999999994))`

But I wish to get `Array(Array[Double])`, how can I do?

Furthermore, I tried to convert all element of `result` to `Math.tan`

If `val z = Array(1, 100, 200)`

I can use `z.map{x => Math.tan(x)}` to achieve.

If array's form like above result, how can I do the same thing?

Thanks for your times.

Comment: The result of a for comprehension depends on the type of the collection that you pass into the for. `0 until x.length` is a `Range` (which is a `IndexedSeq`). Based on that the result will be an `IndexedSeq` and not an `Array`.

Comment: So that explains it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
val z = x.map(arr => (arr zip y).map{case (a, b) => a + b})
```

This will give you `Array[Array[Double]]`. Then you can use:

```
z.map(_.map(Math.tan))
```

to apply `Math.tan()` method on each elements of array.

Comment: Very useful for me